# JUNIT instrumentation test failing in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, junit, instrumentation

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"PARSE ERROR:","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"unsupported class file version 52.0","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"...while parsing com/thoughtworks/xstream/converters/reflection/LambdaConverter.class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"1 error; aborting","sources":[{}]}

:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.Tra
  >   Execution failed for task ':nsformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Added to gradle file :
testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
multiDexEnabled true
But didnt help. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Android doesn't support the Java 8 (version 52.0) class file format (and only supports some Java 8 language level features if you are using the 3.0.0-alpha or later android gradle plugin).  If you control the module/jar that contains com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.LambdaConverter.class, you can recompile it targeting java 7 in order to remove this error.